# SQL Database password

Tags: sql-server

When we import tables from password protected Access database, do it import the passwords too.

How can we make the SQL server database password protected?

Thanks

Furqan

Answer (score 1):

Passwords will be completely separate between Access and SQL Server.

This Microsoft page gives an overview of SQL Server database encryption, which is what I hope you are talking about.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510663.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you make the connection to the database to do the import process Im pretty sure you have to supply credentials to Access. Most databases allow you to create accounts and give them certain rights to certain tables. For an import process only give that process read rights to the tables it is importing.

There is much more to DB security than just login and access rights. Much more than a simple answer can cover.

Here is a link to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648664.aspx) on this topic

Also, if you are worried about security, don't use Access. This is just my opinion.